# Android Studio Shows Error Running App: no target device found

Tags: android, android-studio, pptp, mtp, adb

List of things I have already done, but the problem persists:

1. Enabled USB debugging option in mobile developer options, didnt work so i also enabled allow installing apps via usb, but nope.
2. Changed the USB cable.
3. Installed three types of drivers:

   1. OEM USB driver
   2. Universal USB driver
   3. SDB driver 2.0
      In the device manager each of them recognized my device as Android device and also showed Android composite ADB interface, but because my Android Studio was not recognizing I still installed and uninstalled all of them.
4. Changed USB connection from MTP to PTP.
5. In Android Studio troubleshooting device connections, it says found `6 usb devices not recognized as android devices` and among it is my *Redmi Note 5 Pro*.
6. Restarted ADB server which comes in the same troubleshooting option.
7. Updated Google USB driver in SDK tools.

Apart from all of these if you have any suggestions please answer.

Answer (score 0):

Choose "Run" then "Edit Configurations". In the "General" tab, check the "Deployment Target Options" section.

In my case, the target was already set to "USB Device" and the checkbox "Use same device for future launches" was checked.

I had to change the target to "Show Device Chooser Dialog" and I unchecked the check box. Then my device appeared in the list.

If your device still doesn't appear, then you have to enable USB-Debugging in the smartphone settings again.